# Accessing GUI JTextField objects that are dynamically generated

Tags: java, dynamic, jpanel, instance, jtextfield

I am writing a program that contains a `JButton`. Every time the button is clicked, a new `JTextField` is added to a `JPanel`.

My problem is that, after the user has created all the `JTextFields` and filled them with information, I need to get the text of each field. How can I get access to the `JTextFields` when they are dynamically generated, as they don't have instance names? Is there a better way to get the text of each one, without knowing their instance name.

Here is the code of the `actionPerformed` event of the `JButton`...

```
private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    JTextField x = new JTextField();
    x.setColumns(12);
    p.add(x); 
    validate();
}
```

Comment: Full code, please? I mean, what's `p`?

Comment: p is the panel i put the textfields on.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You say you want to get the text from each field. So, when you create the new instances `x`, why don't you keep a collection of them, such as adding the `JTextFields` to an `ArrayList`?

Alternatively, assuming that `p` is a `JPanel`, you should be able to get all the children, which would be the `JTextFields` that you're adding. Try using `getComponents()` like so...

```
Component[] children = p.getComponents();
for (int i=0;i<children.length;i++){
    if (children[i] instanceof JTextField){
        String text = ((JTextField)children[i]).getText():
    }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant - the single best way to do this is to keep a collection of the newly created objects, that way, you can easily reference them.

Comment: No problem, glad to help. If you're happy with the answer, please remember to 'tick' it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can find them all by looping through the components of the panel (or whatever "p" is). If necessary, check if each is a text box. That is, do p.getComponents and then loop through the returned array. Like:

```
Component[] components=p.getComponents();
for (Component c : components)
{
  if (c instanceof JTextField)
  {
    String value=((JTextField)c).getText();
    ... do whatever ...
  }
}
```

If they are interchangeable, that should be all you need. If you need to distinguish them, I think the cleanest thing to do would be to create your own class that extends JTextField and that has a field for a name or sequence number or whatever you need.