# get text from dynamically added jPanel

Tags: java, swing, io, netbeans-8

I am adding dynamically `subPanel` to `jPanel1` (with `jTextField` and `jButton`). Some of part code was borrowed from [there](http://java-buddy.blogspot.jp/2014/02/java-swing-example-add-and-remove-ui.html).

I am trying to get text from components of `jPanel1`, but cannot succeed.

**EDITED:**
This is a subPanel that contains `jTextField`, `+Button` and `-Button`.

```
private class subPanel extends javax.swing.JPanel {         
        subPanel me;
        public subPanel() {
            super();
            me = this;
            JTextField myLabel = new JTextField(15);
            add(myLabel);
            JButton myButtonRemove = new JButton("-");
            JButton myButtonAdd = new JButton("+");
            add(myButtonRemove);
            add(myButtonAdd);
```

Here is code of AddButton:

```
    jPanel1.add(new subPanel());
    pack();
```

The [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10482796/accessing-gui-jtextfield-objects-that-are-dynamically-generated) that I am trying to get text from `jTextField` doesn't work:

```
     Component[] children = jPanel1.getComponents();
     for (int i=0;i<children.length;i++){
     if (children[i] instanceof JTextField){
     String text = ((JTextField)children[i]).getText();
     System.out.println(text);
```

}

Your response will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You create the new JPanel in addActionPerformed, right? Have you tried to keep the new JPanel as a variable in the context of your Main class and access its members directly?

Comment: @Oliver Schmidt: Yes I created  new JPanel in addActionPerformed, and I tried your suggestion when I declare new JPanel as a variable I couldn't add dynamically jPanels.

Comment: First, the method `void addPanel()` is never called in your code example. Still, that should be the method which adds controls to `jXTaskPane1`, right? Second, the inner class `private class addPanel` adds no further value to the JPanel class it extends. Instead, it confuses the reader :-) Third, when I execute the code, **empty** JPanels (or `addPanel`s) are added to `jXTaskPane1`. Surely you cannot access any controls on an empty JPanel because there is nothing to access! :-) Could you please rewrite the example so that it does what you pointed out in your question?

Comment: @Oliver Schmidt I edited my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is: You are iterating over the children of `jPanel1`:

```
jPanel1.getComponents();
```

And expect there to be a `JTextField`:

```
if (children[i] instanceof JTextField){
     String text = ((JTextField)children[i]).getText();
     System.out.println(text);
}
```

But since you have added `subPanels` to `jPanel1`, the children of jPanel1 are `subPanels`, not `JTextFields`!

So, in order to access the `JTextFields`, you'll have to iterate over the children of the `subPanels` in a second `for-loop`!

**Example:**

```
Component[] children = jPanel1.getComponents();
// iterate over all subPanels...
for (Component sp : children) {
    if (sp instanceof subPanel) {
        Component[] spChildren = ((subPanel)sp).getComponents();
        // now iterate over all JTextFields...
        for (Component spChild : spChildren) {
            if (spChild instanceof JTextField) {
                String text = ((JTextField)spChild).getText();
                System.out.println(text);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your method works nice, but some question comes out. I would like to ask can I get individual access to each `JTextFields`?

Comment: Yes, in the innermost loop you already have access to each of them.

Comment: but if `subPanel` contains 3 `comboBoxes` I cannot manipulate them separately, for example for `jcb1`: `jcb1.getSelectedItem().toString().substring(1, 2)`, for `jcb2`: `jcb2.getSelectedItem().toString().substring(1, 7)`, ... I am always getting `substring(1, 2)` for 3 `comboBoxes`. Is it possible manipulate each individually?

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't sound like good design... To answer your question, you have to recognize which of the panel the loop is currently iterating over. Maybe via `spChild.getName()`?

Answer (score 0):

I know this a bit old question to answer, but still it can potentially help more future viewers.
My initial response was to write this as a comment in @Oliver Schmidt ,  but as I don't have 50 Reputation yet, so decided to write this in a separate answer.

To get access to the components contained in the dynamically added jPanel `"subPanel"`, you don't necessarily need to use second for loop, you can access `subPanel`'s components directly by using the following line of code, for example,

String s1 = **((subPanel) sp)**.jcb1.getSelectedItem().toString().substring(1, 2);
...

So the overall code looks like,

```java
String s1;
String s2;
String s3;
String text;
Component[] c = jPanel1.getComponents();

for (Component sp : c) {
    if (sp instanceof subPanel) {

        //access the component from properly type converted subPanel
        s1 = ((subPanel) sp).jcb1.getSelectedItem().toString().substring(1, 2);
        s2 = ((subPanel) sp).jcb2.getSelectedItem().toString().substring(1, 2);
        s3 = ((subPanel) sp).jcb3.getSelectedItem().toString().substring(1, 2);
        text = ((subPanel) sp).myLabel.getText();
    }
}

System.out.println(s1);
System.out.println(s2);
System.out.println(s3);
System.out.println(text);
```