# get ordered value of jtextfield

Tags: java, swing, io, jtextfield

With the help of [Oliver Schmidt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29749107/get-text-from-dynamically-added-jpanel) I could get text from dynamically added `jTextFields`.

Now I have `jPanel1` with `jTextField1` generated by Netbeans:

```
jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
jPanel1.add(jTextField1);
jPanel1.setLayout(new org.jdesktop.swingx.VerticalLayout());
```

Also by `AddButton` adding dynamic `jTextFields` to `jPanel1`:

```
jPanel1.add(new subPanel());
pack();
```

The problem I get stuck is when I push the SaveButton I am getting not ordered output text.

```
for (Component spChild : spChildren) {
       if (spChild instanceof JTextField) {
             String text = ((JTextField)spChild).getText();
             System.out.println(jTextField1.getText()); //I think this code is wrong
             System.out.println(text);
```

For example, if the value of:

`jTextField1`: 1,

Dynamic `JTextFields`: 2, 3.

Output I am getting repeated `jTextField1`:

1

2

1

3

Desired output is:

1

2

3

I don't know how to avoid this problem.

Comment: How did you set the value in your text fields?

Comment: @Chaker Mallek I am setting value after generating dynamic jTextFields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, you need to remove jTextField1 from your loop and just print it above the loop and then loop through the dynamic text boxes.

```
// Move jTextField1 to print before your print the dynamic JTextBoxes
System.out.println(jTextField1.getText()); 
for (Component spChild : spChildren) {
       if (spChild instanceof JTextField) {
             String text = ((JTextField)spChild).getText();
             System.out.println(text);
```

Comment: You are great. Thank you very much. I am accepting your answer.