# get access to each dynamically added jComponent

Tags: java, swing

Before I already asked question and could get value from dynamically added `jTextFields` and `jComboBoxes` using this [answer for my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29749107/get-text-from-dynamically-added-jpanel).

Now in my `subPanel` I have 3 `jComboBoxes` and 4 `jTextFields`.

To get value of `jComponent` I am using this code:

```
Component[] children = jPanel1.getComponents();
// iterate over all subPanels...
for (Component sp : children) {
    if (sp instanceof subPanel) {
        Component[] spChildren = ((subPanel)sp).getComponents();
        // now iterate over all JTextFields...
        for (Component spChild : spChildren) {
            if (spChild instanceof JTextField) {
                String text = ((JTextField)spChild).getText();
                System.out.println(text);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to ask is it possible to access to each `jComboBoxes` and  `jTextFields` separately, i.e. can I manipulate each `jComponent` and set them different values? How can I achieve this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why not just keep instance variables for each of the `Components` instead of diving into the Component Hierarchy?

Comment: @copeg if possible could you show me some example, my Java skills not so well, but day by day getting well with Stackoverflow

Comment: When adding them dynamically you can keep a reference for each new element in an ArrayList<Components> of Components. this way you know which is which

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to ask is it possible to access to each jComboBoxes and jTextFields separately, i.e. can I manipulate each jComponent and set them different values? How can I achieve this?

Rather than traversing the Component hierarchy (which is fragile to Layout changes), you can keep references to your Components. The following example is a class that contains instance variables for the Child components:

```
public class ComponentWrapper extends JComponent{

    private JComboBox combo;
    private JTextArea textArea;

    public ComponentWrapper(){
        combo = new JComboBox();
        textArea = new JTextArea();
        add(combo);
        add(textArea);
    }

    public Text getTextArea(){
        return textArea;
    }

    public JComboBox getComboBox(){
        return comboBox;
    }
}
```

The above class extends JComponent, adds the components within the constructor, and can be added to another Container elsewhere. *Note the above class is just an example for how to do this, and may need to be further adapted depending upon your requirements.* Usage:

```
ComponentWrapper wrapper = new ComponentWrapper ();
add(wrapper);
revalidate();//if adding 'dynamically'

//later, when you want to get the text
String text = wrapper.getTextArea().getText();
```

Comment: sorry for delay, it takes quite time for me to implement your method and it works well. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Since both of those classes (`JComboBox` and `JTextField`) extend `JComponent` you can make an `ArrayList` and add them to it. i.e.

```
ArrayList<JComponent> components = new ArrayList<JComponent>();
JComboBox pie = new JComboBox();
components.add(pie)
//pie is now stored in components as a JComponent
```

When you need to reference `pie` you can call:

`JComboBox pie = (JComboBox) components.get(0);`

This can be done with any `JComponent` and to reference it you just simply cast it on it's way out. This method, however, can lead to some confusion. So you should either remember the order you add them, or add them in a very specific way (i.e TextFields first, then ComboBoxes).