# remove last comma of dynamic jTextFields

Tags: java, swing

I am getting value of dynamically added `JTextField` using this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29749107/get-text-from-dynamically-added-jpanel):

EDITED:

```
    Component[] children = jPanel1.getComponents();
// iterate over all subPanels...
for (Component sp : children) {
    if (sp instanceof subPanel) {
        Component[] spChildren = ((subPanel)sp).getComponents();
        // now iterate over all JTextFields...
        for (Component spChild : spChildren) {
            if (spChild instanceof JTextField) {
                String text = ((JTextField)spChild).getText();
                System.out.println(text);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output text file I got: `text1,text2,text3,`

Now appeared next problem - "last comma".
I found that Guava can solve the problem, but due to less experience I couldn't implement. If possible could you give me some advice or suggestion.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't think that your edited code produces such an output.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`StringJoiner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html):

```
StringJoiner joiner=new StringJoiner(",");
for (Component spChild : spChildren) {                     
    if (spChild instanceof JTextField) {
        String text = ((JTextField)spChild).getText();
        joiner.add(text);
    }
}
outfile.write(joiner.toString());
```

Comment: I need to use Java 7 so I cannot use `StringJoiner`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if your spChildren is a `List` or an `Array`, my assumption it's `List`, therefore `spChildren.size()` is used, in case its and `Array` `spChildren.length` will replace it.

```
for (int i = 0; i < spChildren.size(); i++) {                     
     if (spChildren.get(i) instanceof JTextField) {
         String text = ((JTextField)spChildren.get(i)).getText();
         if (i == (spChildren.size() - 1)) {
             outfile.write(text);
         } else {
             outfile.write(text + "," );
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: before I posted [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29749107/get-text-from-dynamically-added-jpanel) and using answer of @Oliver Schmidt. Your code I couldn't implement. I don't know why but `length` giving me error.

Comment: Maybe because your spChildren is of type Collection? How do you declare it?
If: List<Component> spChildren = new ArrayList<Component>(), you should use method size()
if: Component[] spChildren  = new Component[5], you 
should use length (which is not a method)

Comment: Right! for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {}

Comment: anyway couldn't succeed