# JAVA: EventHandler for dynamically created button

Tags: java, variables, eventhandler

I have programatically created input fields on my jframe. Now I want to create a save button that will save ALL the results to a database.  I am a beginner with JAVA thus not familiar. I have a entity object for the results, and a controler to save to database. This is not the problem but my problem is writing the event handler.

```
private void jComboBoxSurveyFocusLost(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {                                          
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("PTSchemePU");          
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

    jPanelTests.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));

    Query surveyQ = em.createNamedQuery("Survey.findBySurveyDescription");
    surveyQ.setParameter("surveyDescription", jComboBoxSurvey.getSelectedItem().toString());
    Survey survey = (Survey) surveyQ.getSingleResult();

    int testset_ID = survey.getTestset();

    Query testsetQ = em.createNamedQuery("TestsetV.findByTestSet");
    testsetQ.setParameter("testsetid", testset_ID);
    List<TestsetV> TestSetList = (List<TestsetV>)testsetQ.getResultList();
    totalTests = TestSetList.size();

    JPanel[] myPanel          = new JPanel[totalTests];
    JLabel[] myTestID         = new JLabel[totalTests];
    JTextField [] mytextfield = new JTextField[totalTests];
    JComboBox[] myCombo       = new JComboBox[totalTests];
    JCheckBox[] myNotReturn   = new JCheckBox[totalTests];
    JCheckBox[] myNotEval     = new JCheckBox[totalTests];
    JComboBox[] myReason      = new JComboBox[totalTests];
    JButton[] mySave          = new JButton[totalTests];

    jLabelTestcount.setText(Integer.toString(totalTests));
    jLabelToberesulted.setText(Integer.toString(totalTests));

    for (int tst=0; tst< TestSetList.size(); tst++) {
        myPanel[tst]     = new JPanel();
        myTestID[tst]    = new JLabel();
        mytextfield[tst] = new JTextField();
        myNotReturn[tst] = new JCheckBox("Not Returned");
        myNotEval[tst]   = new JCheckBox("Not Evaluated");
        myReason[tst]    = new JComboBox();
        mySave[tst]      = new JButton("Save");

        Query qR = em.createNamedQuery("Lookups.findByLookupType");
        qR.setParameter("lookupType","REAS");
        java.util.List<Lookups> reasonList = (java.util.List<Lookups>)qR.getResultList();

        for (int i = 0 ; i < reasonList.size(); i++) {
            Lookups lu = reasonList.get(i);
            myReason[tst].addItem(lu.getLookupDescription());
        }

        myPanel[tst].setLayout(new SpringLayout());
        int rows =1;
        int cols = 5;

        myPanel[tst].setSize(10, 10);
           myPanel[tst].setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(javax.swing.border.BevelBorder.RAISED));
        myPanel[tst].setVisible(true);
        jPanelTests.add(myPanel[tst]);
        mytextfield[tst].setSize(10, 10);
        myNotReturn[tst].setName("No Return");
        myNotEval[tst].setName("Not Evauated");

        JLabel testName = new JLabel(TestSetList.get(tst).getTestDesctiption());
        myPanel[tst].add(new JLabel(Integer.toString(TestSetList.get(tst).getTestsId())));

        myPanel[tst].add(testName);

      switch (TestSetList.get(tst).getTestSetup()){
        case "TEXT" : {     
          myPanel[tst].add(mytextfield[tst]); 

          break;
        }
        case "COMB" : {
            Query q = em.createNamedQuery("Lookups.findByLookupType");
            q.setParameter("lookupType",TestSetList.get(tst).getLookup() );
            java.util.List<Lookups> lookupList = (java.util.List<Lookups>)q.getResultList();

            for (int i = 0 ; i < lookupList.size(); i++) {
                Lookups lu = lookupList.get(i);

                cb.addItem(lu.getLookupCode());
            }

            myPanel[tst].add(cb);

         break;
        } 

        case "SPIN" : {
             myPanel[tst].add(sp);

            break;
        }
    } // end switch

      myPanel[tst].add(myNotReturn[tst]);
      myPanel[tst].add(myNotEval[tst]);
      myPanel[tst].add(myReason[tst]); 
      myPanel[tst].add(mySave[tst]);

      SpringUtilities.makeCompactGrid(myPanel[tst], 1, myPanel[tst].getComponentCount(),6,6,6,6);  
    }
    pack();
    jPanelTests.setVisible(true);         
}
```

I then created a event handeler when the panel loses focus

```
myPanel[tst].addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {


               @Override
               public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
                   throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
               }

               @Override
               public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
                     myResults[tst].setResultValue(mytextfield[tst].getText());

               }
           });
```

But now I get a error (local variables refferenced from an inner classmust be final of effectivly final)  on the line `myResults[tst].setResultValue(mytextfield[tst].getText());`

How can I reference to the value entered in the jTextField/JComboBox/jSpinner

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your counter variable tst is not final (meaning no final keyword is used), nor effectively final (meaning it is modified), and as such, it cannot be referensed from an inner class - in your case an instance of FocusListener.

You cannot mark tst as final, as you modify it - but you can create a new variable in the body of the loop.

Note that effecively final concept is new to Java8, in earlier versions you had to be explicit and add final keyword to all local variables accessed from inner class.

Study the example below:

```
public class TestFinalVariables {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String effectivelyFinal = "aaa";
        for (int tst=0; tst< 10; ++tst) {
            final int j = tst;  //explicit final not necessary here
            new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    System.out.println(effectivelyFinal);
                    System.out.println(j);
                    //System.out.println(tst); Won't compile

                }
            }.run();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I got a answer with [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29749107/get-text-from-dynamically-added-jpanel)